# scope error message

Tags: c++, scope, class-design

Hey guys, just learning about composition of classes and ran into this error.

**Gradebook.h**

```
  #ifndef GRADEBOOK_h
#define GRADEBOOK_h

#include "StudentRec.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class GradeBook
{
public:
    GradeBook();

    GradeBook(string initLastName, int studGrades);

    void AddStudent(string initLastName, int studGrades);

    void ShowStudents();

    void UserInterface();

private:
    static const int numStudents=20;
    StudentRec student[numStudents];
    static int studentCounter;
    static int gradeCounter;
};

#endif
```

**Gradebook.cpp**

```
     #include "Gradebook.h"
#include "StudentRec.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

GradeBook::GradeBook()
{}

GradeBook::GradeBook(string initLastName, int studGrades)
{}

void GradeBook::AddStudent(string initLastName, int studGrades)
{   
    gradeCounter++;   //Increments variable responsible for tracking # of grades per student
    StudentRec newStudent(initLastName, studGrades); //creates new student object
    student[studentCounter]=newStudent;  //Assigns new student object to array
    studentCounter++;  //Increments variable responsible for tracking # of students
}

void GradeBook::ShowStudents()
{
    for(int i=0;i<studentCounter; i++){  //Displays information for each student instance
        cout<<student[i].GetLastName()<<' ';
        for(int j=0; j<gradeCounter; j++)        
            cout<<student[i].GetGrades(j)<<' ';
        cout<<endl;
    }
}

void GradeBook::UserInterface()
{
    char choice=' ';
    string studLastName;
    int studGrade;

    cout<<"Welcome to GradeBook, this program stores students"
    <<" grades by last name.  To ADD a student press the 'A'"
    <<" key.  To LIST all students, press the 'L' key.  To "
    <<" QUIT, press the 'Q' key."<<endl<<endl;

    cin>>choice;

    choice=toupper(choice);

    while(choice!='Q')
    {
        if(choice='A'){
            cout<<"To add a student, please enter their last name"
            <<" followed by a space and a non-negative grade"
            <<" Ex. McClure 96";
            cin>>studLastName>>studGrade;

            AddStudent(studLastName, studGrade);
        }

        else if(choice='L'){
            cout<<"This is a list of all students in GradeBook"
            <<endl<<endl;

            ShowStudents(); //Displays all StudentRec objects
        }

        else if(choice!='Q')
            cout<<"Please enter another letter"<<endl;

        cout<<"To ADD a student press the 'A' key.  To LIST all students, press the 'L' key.  To "
        <<" QUIT, press the 'Q' key."<<endl<<endl;      
    }
}
```

**Main.cpp**

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
#include "StudentRec.h"
#include "Gradebook.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    GradeBook gradeBook;

    UserInterface();

    return 0;

}
```

**StudentRec.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "StudentRec.h"

using namespace std;

StudentRec::StudentRec()
{
    lastName=" ";
    for(int i=0;i<numGrades; i++)
        grades[i]=0;
}

StudentRec::StudentRec(string initLastName, int studGrade)
{
    static int gradeCounter=0;
    lastName=initLastName;
    grades[gradeCounter]=studGrade;
}

string StudentRec::GetLastName()
{
    return lastName;
}

int StudentRec::GetGrades(int gradeNum)
{
    return grades[gradeNum];
}

void StudentRec::AddGrades(int studGrade)
{

    gradeCounter++;
    if(gradeCounter<=numGrades)
        grades[gradeCounter]=studGrade;
    else
        cout<<"Too many grades for this student";
}
```

**StudentRec.h**

```
#ifndef STUDENTREC_h
#define STUDENTREC_h

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class StudentRec
{
public:
    StudentRec();

    StudentRec(string initLastName, int studGrade);

    string GetLastName();

    int GetGrades(int gradeNum);

    void AddGrades(int studGrade);

private:
    static const int numGrades=10;
    static int gradeCounter;
    string lastName;
    int grades[numGrades];
};

#endif
```

In the Main.cpp file, I get an error I can't find the solution for.  It reads 
*error: "UserInterface" was not declared in this scope*.  I got this error while compiling in XCode
I got *error C3861: 'UserInterface': identifier not found*

Obviously i've tried it in two IDEs, I also have the StudentRec.cpp and .h, but not sure you need them.  Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Generally it's considered bad style to use `string` without qualification, especially in the public interface of a class. You should use `std::string` instead. And also, why are `GradeBook`'s variables `static`?

Comment: That's "generally" nonsense. What might be considered bad style is `using namespace std` in a header file that puts it into global scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that `UserInterface()` is actually a member function of `GradeBook`, correct?

If so, you need to add a declaration for the member function in the `GradeBook` class declaration:

```
class GradeBook
{
public:
    GradeBook();
    GradeBook(string initLastName, int studGrades);
    void AddStudent(string initLastName, int studGrades);
    void ShowStudents();

    void UserInterface(); // Added

    // ...
private:
    // ...
};
```

This way, the compiler will "know" that the `UserInterface()` function exists as a member function. You then provided the definition in `void GradeBook::UserInterface()` in your `.cpp` file.

Then you need to call it on a `GradeBook` instance, like the `gradeBook` variable in your `main()` function:

```
int main()
{
    GradeBook gradeBook;
    // This calls the member function UserInterface() on the gradeBook variable.
    gradeBook.UserInterface();
    // This calls the global UserInterface(), which doesn't exist.
    // UserInterface();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I apologize, it seems I added the wrong version of my code.  The error I got includes that code. Were that the case, I think i'd have a few more

Comment: Now it seems i'm getting the error message: Missing ';' before '.' on the same line twice.

Comment: @ChadM: I think the error originates in `StudentRec.h`. Check to see if you're missing any semicolons in that document.

Comment: could you take a look at it now that i've posted the StudentRec.h file?

Answer (score 1):

`UserInterface()` is a method of `GradeBook`.  The call probably needs to be:

```
gradeBook.UserInterface();
```

Comment: Well, I did that, now I have 2 errors saying the same thing in the same place. On VS it says missing ';' before '.'

Comment: @ChadM: It also looks like you need to add the declaration to the class (as In silico) pointed out.  I'm not sure that accounts for that particular error, but it does need to be declared in the class definition.

Comment: @ChadM: This sounds like a dumb question, but did you forget the semicolon `;` on the variable declaration `GradeBook gradeBook;`?

Comment: Yeah, somehow I managed to copy and paste an old version of the code when I was swapping the files over to a pc.

Comment: Yep, i'm green, but I like to think not that green :)